# Changing increasing rate

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
thing = 0
while True:
    code = raw_input("")
    thing += len(code)
    if code == "doubler":
        thing += len(code) * 2
```

I want to double the increasing rate of the `thing`. But if I write `thing = len(code)*2` it resets the value to double of the input. If I write `thing += len(code)*2` it just adds double of input and doesn't effect other inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want to achieve is that after one types 'doubler', the multiplication should be carried out for all future inputs. If so, perhaps what you are looking for is something like

```
thing = 0
doubling = False
while True:
    code = raw_input("")
    if code == "doubler":
    doubling = True
    thing += len(code)*2 if doubling else len(code)
```

Answer (score 0):

Good?

```
thing = 0
add = 1
limit = 50
while limit > 0:
    print thing
    thing += add
    add = add * 2
    limit -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that what you want is to double the effect of `len(code)` whenever `code` is equal to `code=="doubler"` and for the future inputs as well. Then you need to keep track of how many times you encounter `"doubler"`. The following might work for you:

```
thing = 0
scale = 1
while True:
    code = raw_input("")
    thing += scale*len(code)
    if code == "doubler":
        scale *= 2
```

Comment: This might be work but I want to add more like "doubler". Please write me if you find a better way. Thanks for your suggestion. It works btw.

Comment: What do you mean by more like "doubler"? Do you want to add another keywords for the same effect?

Comment: yes kinda. I want to  add things like increasing = increasing * 5%